# PHP file_get_contents of CSS file including @import

Tags: php

I am attempting to load the contents of a css file to a PHP string. It works great, except when the css file makes use of `@import`:

style.css

```
@import url('normalize.css');
@import url('main.css');
@import url('colors.css');

$contents = @file_get_contents('style.css');

echo $contents; // Obviously doesn't include the css in the imported files
```

This is obviously returning the exact contents of `style.css`. How can I get it to import those files?

Comment: Write a CSS parser in PHP---or, because no one has time for that, use regex and find all occurrences of `^@import\s\+url\(` then include those files in the same order as the CSS says to. Note: regex'ing this is horribly flawed because you may end up concatenating all these styles together in an order that is different from how browsers would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky but an easy way to do it:
first add comment with @import after all imports

## css_part

```
@import url('normalize.css');
@import url('main.css');
@import url('colors.css');
/*@import*/
.class{}
.class{}
```

## php_part

```
$contents = @file_get_contents('style.css');
$wordToLookFor = "@import";
$contentToAdd = "";
$imports = explode($wordToLookFor,$contents);
for( $i=0; $i < sizeof($imports) - 1 ; $i++){
    $tmp = str_replace(array("url(",");","/*"),"",$imports[$i]);
    $contentToAdd .= @file_get_contents($tmp);
}
$contents = $contentsToAdd . $contents;
echo $contents; // should include other files in the same order now
```

Comment: i wrote this directly here so it might have some errors. Try it and change it but it should work ;)